# authorization required

Tags: applications

I can't access play store and when I attacked in war in my clash of clan it disconnect.. by the way the error message when I access play store is authentication required... please guys help me... I already reset my tablet.. clear data play store and uninstalled updates and remove and re add my Google account but nothinng work... when I tried to sync my Google account sync error... I provided all the things I did.. any immediate response are highly appreciated.... please guys help me

Answer (score 0):

Just one thing to try: change your Google account password online and then sign back in on your Android device.

Comment: i already changed my password

Comment: OK. Sorry, I'm not sure what to try then...

Comment: thanks for the advised thou... by the way newly created accounts are working

Comment: Newly created accounts?

Comment: i mean,, i just created a new account and it sync fine, i can access play store and play clash of clans fine

Comment: Glad to hear it! Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: ah... even google team doesn't reply at all,, i hope my gmail will sync again.. thanks again ^_^